# Select all from a table ORDER BY another tables column, with match primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been looking for a while but the query I am trying to accomplish seems fairly hard to find any information or documentation on how to do what I am trying to do.

I have two tables, one of them stores my user accounts and basic information. I then have a second table that holds a little more information about the user.

Both of these tables have primary keys (table one is `id` and table two is `user_id`) which I use to know who is who and match records between both tables.

What I am trying to do today is I want to get 10 records from table one, order by a column in table two (room_count) DESC.

Table #1's name is "users" and Table #2's name is "user_information".

**What have I tried?**
I'm not really sure where to start so I haven't tried anything yet.

How would I got about doing something like this?
Thank you to any answers posted.

For example, let's say I have 4 users, I'll write the username followed by the room_count column in the other table below.

```
Adam Sandler : 4
Jenny Hang : 9
Peter Foreign : 0
```

If I was to use the query with ASC it would start with `Peter Foreign` and end with `Jenny Hang`

Comment: . . The tags were SQL Server and MySQL.  I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just need a simple join?

```
SELECT 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_information ON users.id = user_information.user_id 
ORDER BY user_information.room_count DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked with a few small modifications: SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_information ON users.id = user_information.user_id ORDER BY user_information.room_count DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: `ORDER BY user_information.room_count ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
 INNER JOIN user_info ui
    ON u.id = ui.user_id 
 ORDER BY ui.room_count DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something basic like

```
select users.*
from
  users, user_information
where
  users.id =user_information.user_id
order by
  user_information.room_count
  desc
Limit 10
```

Edit: changed `select users.id` to `select users.*` to better fit the question asked.